# how to add values with separated comma in datagridview column in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I add values with separated commas in a `DataGridView` `Column`.
I want something like this on my `Options` column, e.g., Spicy, Extra Cheese, etc. any value.

I just tried this by my own logic but it replaces the existing value:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Sauce_Name From Sauces Where Sauce_Name = '" + Sauce_name + "' ", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    if (Sales_Grid.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        int n = Sales_Grid.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = dr["Sauce_Name"].ToString();
    }
}
con.Close();
```

Current result:
[image: See Image for more details:]

Desired result:
[image]

Comment: So you want Spicy,Extra Cheese, etc all in one column?

Comment: You are just assigning and reassigning a value in a loop.  Loop thru, save them up as one string  then update the DGV.  Also, always use SQL parameters, never glue strings together to make a query

Comment: In one cell, see image please

Comment: How are these adjectives coming in? string[]? List<string>? string?

Comment: @Plutonix Actually i haven't tried this before that's why i am doing it wrong with loop. I need just a sample code to solve this problem.

Comment: i edited my image to show what i exactly want to do :https://imgur.com/a/60ypGRC

Comment: @G.LC these adjective are coming from database.

Comment: You either need to concatenate them in the select or when setting the cell values. Up to you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = dr["Sauce_Name"].ToString();
```

instead of writing the above, try the code below

```
if(Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value.ToString()=="")
   Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = dr["Sauce_Name"].ToString();
else
  Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = 
Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value.Tostring() + ","+dr["Sauce_Name"].ToString();
```

Comment: Getting error `object reference is not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: It's working now after changing it `(Sales_Grid.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value==null)`.